# How to wait for a child component task to be completed before proceed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, parent, communication

this is my first question here, sorry if it's not well structured.

I have a parent component, component1, that has a form,
and it calls component2, which also has a form. 
Component2 has its own database collection, but it only can be saved if parent component were too. So it has an Input property called `write`, that component1 set to true when user click on save button.

This Input is been checked with OnChanges, by component2.
NgOnChanges call `writeOnDB()`, and this is working fine.

writeOnDB try to persists the component2 form data, and emit an Output `saved`, with true on success, or false on fail.

So, component2 is being called like this:

```
<component2 
    [write]="saveForm" 
    (saved)="onCmp2Saved($event)">
</component2>
```

My submit function is like this:

```
onSubmit(form) {
    // Get form values and save into component1 object
    this.cmp1 = form;

    // Set Flag to save component2 on BD
    this.saveForm = true;

    let result = this._cmp1Service.editData(this.cmp1)

    //TODO: Check if component2 successfully saved its form before proceed

    result.subscribe(
        res => _router.navigate['home'],
        error => ...
    );
}
```

So the question is,
how do I wait for the component2 emit `saved` output?

I always find my answers here, but I think I'm not knowing how to search this, cause I didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to wait for two things to happen before you continue:

1. a `saved` event from component2
2. an event from `editData()`

Since you don't know which will finish first, you'll need each handler to check to see if the other completed.  Something like:

```ts
onSubmit(form) {
    this.cmp1 = form;
    this.saveForm = true;
    this.component2Done = false;
    this.component1Done = false;
    this._cmp1Service.editData(this.cmp1).subscribe(
        res => {
           this.component1Done = true;
           if(this.component2Done) { doSomething(); }
        },
        error => ...
    );
}
onCmp2Saved(result) {
     this.component2Done = true;
     if(this.component1Done) { doSomething(); }
}
```